# How to stop timer running after getting response from client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing a game where i need to send every tick of timer to the users in socket room. And if my timer is of 30s sec , i want reply from one of client  in that 30 sec.I cant define global variable to stop timer because there can be multiple game running at server side.I want to check if server getting  response or not in that 30 sec.

```
socket.on('decidedturn_ack', function (game_id) {  
   socket.join("room-"+game_id);
   var timeLeft = 30;
   var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
   function countdown() {
         if (timeLeft == 0) {
                clearTimeout(timerId); 
               io.sockets.in("room-"+game_id).emit('time_up',arr);
         } else { 
              io.sockets.in("room-"+game_id).emit('timeLeft',timeLeft);
              timeLeft--;
         }
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Since a global variable is not an option, you can store the timer on the socket object which is unique for each connected socket.

```
var timeLeft = 30;
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
socket.timerId = timerId; // assign the timer to the socket for use later..
```

Once a response is received do something like this:

```
socket.on('decidedturn_response', function (game_id) { 
    clearTimeout(socket.timerId); // clears the timer on response
});
```